# MongoDb C# : Bulk Insert vs Bulk Update

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

So I need to insert a lot of records (millions) into a MongoDB table, I have been using BulkWriteAsync with UpdateOneModel because a record may exist already and I have an **index on the URL**

Is this the fastest way to bulk insert records, I don't want to update anything, but I don't want an exception if there is a Duplicate Key exception

```
var updateOneModels = urls.Select(x =>
{
    var filterDefinition = Builders<UrlDoc>.Filter.Eq(p => p.Url, x.Url);
    var updateDefinition = Builders<UrlDoc>.Update.SetOnInsert(p => p.Lang, x.Lang)
        .SetOnInsert(p => p.Status, x.Status)
        .SetOnInsert(p => p.Mine, x.Mine);

    return new UpdateOneModel<UrlDoc>(filterDefinition, updateDefinition) { IsUpsert = true };
}).ToList();

var resultWrites = await collection.BulkWriteAsync(updateOneModels);
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/#error-handling With unordered insert errors won't block

Comment: Do you know how to do the write concern to?

Comment: It does
MongoDB.Driver.Core.Operations.MongoBulkWriteOperationException: 'A bulk write operation resulted in one or more errors.
  E11000 duplicate key error collection: WEB.wet index: url_1 dup key: { url: "http://000.558psb.com/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=36" }

Comment: it's ordered by default. Add `IsOrdered = false` option.

Comment: IsOrdered helped mate if you want to put that as an answer